# Designing Borders with QGIS

Tags: qgis, cartography, borders

My task is to reproduce a map of a specific place. The problem are the borders which I can´t reproduce in QGIS.

The attached picture shows the line. It looks like a polygon filled with slashes.

[image: d]

Any ideas how I could reproduce this?

Comment: Can you include your picture here on GIS SE instead of an external link? Also asking about two software products in one question often tends the question beeing closed as too broad. I recommend asking two separate questions about each software.

Comment: added image from link

Comment: It would be much easier to solve the problem in QGIS. Thanks for adding the image!

Comment: Do you have any ideas for that issue?

Comment: Borders like this are usually line features or borders of polygons. Or do you have the border itself as polygon?

Comment: No it´s a line layer or a filled polygon with no or transparent filling.

Comment: What are you having trouble to reproduce? The line filled polygon or the big green border at the top of the map?

Comment: Oh I´m sorry, its the line filled polygon :-) 
How can I produce something like that without having a polygon layer with this dimensions?

Comment: Hint. Geometry generator and add buffer for line and that will make polygon, style as polygon. Fast typing from mobile.

Comment: You can use QGIS' symbology tool to produce a pattern by superimposing black lines rotated over a thick white line, but for cartographic purpose I suggest you create a buffer with the wanted width (beware it's scale dependent unlike the symbology tool) and then fill it with the pattern you want.

Comment: If any of the answers fills your need, please mark it as "accepted": it will help other users.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 13):

### Option 1 - Quickest way

There is actually a quite immediate way to obtain that effect:

- double click on the layer you want to style (in your case the `border` layer)
- under `Symbology` select `Hashed line`
- play around with the settings. To obtain something similar to the example of the question, set `Rotation` to `45°` (or `-45°`)

[image: image showing how to set a hatched border for a polygon in QGIS]

### Option 2 - Quick way

Always through a style-based only approach, a more refined way is to:

- use the `Geometry generator` feature of QGIS to create a buffer at render time (I just set this to `Polygon/MultiPolygon`, then `buffer($geometry,55)`),
- fill it with a light background
- add a hashed fill

Much nicer effect, IMHO:

[image]

details about the hash filling
[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! I found the function - I used QGIS 3.4 and there´s no such function - downloading a newer version :-)

Comment: This can be quite messy with coarse boundaries, it depends on the result you want. But for cartography, you might want to go for the buffer/dissolve method as it will prevent overlapping hashed lines.

Comment: @RafDouglas, which program did you used for the screen shots and including the steps via numbers?

Comment: @whyzar I use a (quite old and unmaintained, but still excellent) program called HotShot (https://sourceforge.net/projects/hotshots/)

Answer (score 6):

You could create the border as a line then buffer the line the right distance (it will depend of your map scale) to get a polygon and style this polygon with a line pattern fill and no border.

To create the buffer you may use the tool from the processing toolbox (create a new polygon layer) or use the geometry generator in the border line style (better if you dont want to create new layer)

EDIT

The geometry generator expression will be like this :

```
 buffer( $geometry,50,1)
```

it create a 50m buffer (the buffer unit is the same as layer unit, in this case meters) with pointy end (second value : 1, the bigger the value the more the end are circular)

Comment: Thank´s a lot! I´ll try that one and let you know if it worked! :-)

Answer (score 5):

Open the symbology menu of your layer and choose `outline marker line`.

[image]

Make sure to uncheck `rotate marker`.

[image]

Then navigate to `simple marker`.

[image]

Choose the `line` as symbol and rotate it by `-45°`.

[image]

Do additional styles if you wish.

Answer (score 3):

[image]
If you have an already existing polygon layer, you can simply do something like this:
(Polygon with line pattern fill, no border)
[image]
[image]